# $http.get not reflecting database change

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, wcf

I have an ASP.NET project running AngularJS that is accessing a WCF service that uses a database. It's a simple CRUD interface with a table displaying the database data and options for adding, editing, and deleting data. After a user adds (ie: `$http.post`), edits (ie: `$http.put`) or deletes an entry (ie: `$http.delete`), my controller calls `$http.get` and uses it to update the table. All of the requests use the "promise" structure and will catch errors.

Sometimes after putting a request through, the table will not update after the change. I have checked, and the data retrieved from the get request does not include the change. But, if I reload the page, the change will be present. Why is this happening, and why only sometimes? Does there need to be a delay or something between the `post`/`put`/`delete` request and the get request? Is this a server or a client problem? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

When checking the actual requests in chrome dev tools network during a failed update, I found that two calls to the create/delete/update service would be made followed by the GET request. The first is always an OPTIONS request, followed by the actual POST/DELETE/PUT request. Earlier, in order to get these services working with my interface, I had to modify the services Global.asax.cs file with the following:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
}
```

The problem might be here. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

The save function in my controller:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    // Store user inputs
    var Map = {
        Id: $scope.Id,
        Channel: $scope.Channel,
        SubChannel: $scope.SubChannel,
        ChannelStatus: $scope.ChannelStatus,
        MappedStatus: $scope.MappedStatus
    };
    var post = CRUD_AngularJS_RESTService.post(Map);
    post.then(function (pl) {
        // Clear input forms
        ClearModels();
        $scope.ResultMessage = "New entry " + pl.data.Id + " added";
        $scope.AddEntry = false;
        // Re-populate table with new data
        GetFullMap();
    },
        function (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
        });
};
```

GetFullMap() is another function in the controller:

```
function GetFullMap() {
    var get = CRUD_AngularJS_RESTService.getFullMap();
    get.then(function (pl) {
        console.log("here ", pl.data);
        // Display map data in table
        $scope.Maps = pl.data;
        console.log($scope.Maps);
    },
        function (errorPl) {
            $scope.ResultMessage = "Error loading map";
            console.log("Error occurred while retrieving map ", errorPl);
        });
}
```

And in Services.js, the post function:

```
// Create new record
this.post = function (Map) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:63647/Services.svc/rest/MapCreate",
        data: Map
    });
    return request;
}
```

Also in Services, the get function:

```
this.getFullMap = function () {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:63647/MerchantServices.svc/rest/FullMapRead");
};
```

Comment: check the actual request in dev tools network , might be cached which would be a 304 status. Check your headers also

Comment: @charlietfl I just checked this... when loading the page the first GET request gets response 200. When adding a new entry, there is a POST (with response 200) followed by a GET (response 200). When the page doesn't update properly, there are actually TWO calls to the create service; the first is an OPTIONS request, the other is the POST. This is probably related, right?

Comment: OPTIONS is a cross domain preflight request. Why don't you return the data in first request? Also show the code , are you waiting for first request before making second one?

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, please see Edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening, but this workaround seems to fix things, I just added a little delay before calling GetFullMap():

```
$scope.save = function () {
    // Store user inputs
    var Map = {
        Id: $scope.Id,
        Channel: $scope.Channel,
        SubChannel: $scope.SubChannel,
        ChannelStatus: $scope.ChannelStatus,
        MappedStatus: $scope.MappedStatus
    };
    var post = CRUD_AngularJS_RESTService.post(Map);
    post.then(function (pl) {
        // Clear input forms
        ClearModels();
        $scope.ResultMessage = "New entry " + pl.data.Id + " added";
        $scope.AddEntry = false;
        // Re-populate table with new data
        $timeout(GetFullMap, 100);
    },
        function (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
        });
};
```

Also be sure to provide $timeout in the app.controller function:

```
app.controller("CRUD_AngularJS_RESTController", function($scope, CRUD_AngularJS_RESTService, $timeout)
{
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use?

Old ie version (ie9) have an aggressive caching strategy.
Sometime it will cache your get http request...

You will have to set a no-cache param in the header of the server response, or just add a timestamp parameter to each request (so that each request are different).

http://myContext/myService?timestamp=1350387905444

Comment: Using Chrome... the server response already does have a no-cache parameter in the header.